# Omniauth devise with username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

On using Omniauth and devise, for signing up or registrations we have Email,Password & Password Confirmation as default field, is it possible to have username, password and email and not the default one.

Comment: [Read devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

To do that, add this code to your `config/initializers/devise.rb`

`config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]`

However, it will not appear on the registration form. So you should move it to your application through the `rails g devise:views` command and modify the `registrations#new` form_for to the code above.

```
<%= f.label :username %><br />
<%= f.text_field :username %>

<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>

<%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %>
```